# Implementar RadioButton en ListView

Tags: android, listview, radiobutton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede observar en la imagen he agregado radio buttons en mi lista, pero solo quiero que se pueda seleccionar una, estoy usando `simpleCursorAdapter`

puedo seleccionar un item de la siguiente manera y sin problema agregandole a mi variable el nombre del item seleccionado.

```
....
String folio;  
Seleccionado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView infofolio = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
                TextView infohuerto = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtHuerto);

                    folio = infofolio.getText().toString();


            }
        });
```

pero como podria utilizar la parte de los radiobuttons y que solo pueda seleccionarse uno y pasar el nombre a mi variable folio?

Comment: Podrias poner le código de tu adaptador, en donde creas tu listView

Comment: Para seleccionar un solo RabioButton debe ir dentro de un RadioGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto en tu XML

```
    <RadioButton 
       ...
       android:onClick="onClickRadioButton"
       ...
     />
```

y esto en Java :

```
       private RadioButton listRadioButton = null;
       int listIndex = -1;

    public void onClickRadioButton(View v) {
    View vMain = ((View) v.getParent());

    if (listRadioButton != null) listRadioButton.setChecked(false);
    listRadioButton = (RadioButton) v;
    if (listRadioButton.isChecked) {
        listIndex = ((ViewGroup) vMain.getParent()).indexOfChild(vMain); 
    /*tu logica aqui folio = infofolio.getText().toString();
    TextView infofolio = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
    TextView infohuerto = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtHuerto);
    */
    } else {
        listRadioButton = null;
        listIndex = -1
    }
}
```

Comment: funciona perfecto, ahora me permite seleccionar solo uno, pero como paso el valor a la variable `folio` a partir del radio que se selecciono no soy muy bueno en android.

Comment: solo te falta ir a buscar el valor de tu lista , ya que guardas el indice en la variable listIndex , si gustas indicame todo el código que tienes y te devuelvo como debe quedar :).